# jquery for disabling multiple checkboxes on selection of other checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a HTML code where I have 7 boxes in a div.Below is the html code.

```html
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" aria-expanded="true">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">            
              <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypeCertification" name="validationTypesDone" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px" />
           <label>Certification</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
              <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypeFunctional" name="validationTypesDone" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px" />
           <label>Functional</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
               <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypeLCM" name="validationTypesDone[]" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px" />
           <label>LCM</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
               <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypePerformance" name="validationTypesDone[]" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px"  />
           <label>Performance</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
               <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypeResilience" name="validationTypesDone[]" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px" />
           <label>Resilience</label>
            </div>            
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
               <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypeSecurity" name="validationTypesDone[]" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px"  />
           <label>Security</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
               <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypeSystemVerification" name="validationTypesDone[]" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px" />
           <label>System verification</label>
            </div>
```

1)Now if i select the checkbox "Certification" then all other should be automatically disabled.

2)If System Verification is checked (all the other automatically on checked and grey out)(Certification on No and grey out)

3)if other options are individually selected then (Certification and System Verification on No and grey out)

please let me know how i can get the functionality

Below is the code which i tried.

```js
$('input[name="validationTypesDone"]').on('change', function() {
         var val = $(this).attr('value');
         switch(val) {
         case 'Certification':
           if($(this).is(':checked')){
           $('input[name="validationTypesDone"],input[name="validationTypesDone[]"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $(this).prop('disabled', false)
        } else {
          $('input[name="validationTypesDone"],input[name="validationTypesDone[]"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }            
           break;
         case 'System verification':
           if($(this).is(':checked')){
           $('input[name="validationTypesDone"],input[name="validationTypesDone[]"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('input[name="validationTypesDone"],input[name="validationTypesDone[]"]').prop('checked', true);
        $('input[id="validationTypeCertification"]').prop('checked', false);        
        $(this).prop('disabled', false)
         } else {
            $('input[name="validationTypesDone"],input[name="validationTypesDone[]"]').prop('disabled', false);
         }
             break;
        
       } 
        });
```

Above is working for option 1 and 2..For 3rd option can you give me the best solution.

Comment: post your code also which you have tried so far..

Comment: i have updated the question with my peice of code i am trying...but unable to get for 3rd option.

Comment: Should they be unchecked and disabled?

Comment: It should be unchecked and disabled

Answer (score 0):

This demo implements only one of the functionality where checking of `Certification` disabled all other. Hopefully you will able to implement the other two

Here jquery selector is check if an input with name `validationTypesDone` is checked
and if the `id` is `validationTypeCertification` then get all other input with other name
and disbled them using `prop` function

```js
$('input[name="validationTypesDone"]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked') && $(this)[0].id === 'validationTypeCertification') {
    $('input[name="validationTypesDone"],input[name="validationTypesDone[]"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).prop('disabled', false)
  } else {
    $('input[name="validationTypesDone"],input[name="validationTypesDone[]"]').prop('disabled', false);
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" aria-expanded="true">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypeCertification" name="validationTypesDone" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px" />
      <label>Certification</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypeFunctional" name="validationTypesDone" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px" />
      <label>Functional</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypeLCM" name="validationTypesDone[]" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px" />
      <label>LCM</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypePerformance" name="validationTypesDone[]" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px" />
      <label>Performance</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypeResilience" name="validationTypesDone[]" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px" />
      <label>Resilience</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypeSecurity" name="validationTypesDone[]" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px" />
      <label>Security</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <input type="checkbox" id="validationTypeSystemVerification" name="validationTypesDone[]" style="width:15px;height:15px;margin-right:20px" />
      <label>System verification</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly for certification...but i need for others too.